# Populate NSForm with NSComboBoxes

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

So I have a task of reading from an xml file which contains a description of what form fields and comboboxes should exist in a dialog. I started by using NSForm and addentry to add the form fields, but then found out NSMatrix may be required to add combobox cells dynamically.

So my questions are:

1) Since NSForm inherits from NSMatrix can I add combobox cells to NSForm after I add the text fields.

2) If I have to use NSMatrix, does anyone have any good sample code they can point me to or write which adds a text field, and combobox to it at runtime and then resizes the NSMatrix to fit its contents. A lot of books just describe what NSMatrix is, and show how to populare it using interface builder.

Comment: Up-voted for being a good question about control/cell topics in Cocoa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NSForm does not allow custom cell types (text field only) and NSMatrix takes only one cell type (you cannot have an NSMatrix that has a mix of NSTextFieldCell and NSComboBoxCell).

If you really need to create a variable number of rows of field + combo box, you're going to have to manage the creation, layout, and destruction of these manually.

Alternatively, you might consider using [collection views](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CollectionViews/).

**Update** - If you're targeting 10.7 and up and need better control than collection views offer, consider using [view-based table views](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/ViewBasedTables/ViewBasedTables.html).

Comment: Actually, it is possible to add mixed cells into NSMatrix. It is described in Cocoa Developers Handbook in chapter 12.4.1. See it on Google Books.